# remove text followed by text "Edit" inside a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<h2 class="pagetitle"><em>Edit Site Update</em> Site Update</h2>
```

In the above code, how to remove text followed by "Edit" in em tag using jquery? 
So that any text comes after text Edit in em tag, will be removed.

Comment: So you want the result to be `<h2 class="pagetitle"><em>Edit</em> Site Update</h2>`?

Comment: how about using "$('h2.pagetitle em').text('Edit');"?

Comment: What is the context? Why you have to do this instead of producing the right html directly?

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
$('.pagetitle em').text('Edit')
```

Comment: Was about to post exactly the same xD. +1